# SCRIPT_NAME does not match REQUEST_URI with web.py in apache cgid module

Tags: python, apache, web.py

I am trying to deploy my web.py application in Apache with mod_cgid module.

I have defined the urls like this in urls.py

```
urls = (
    '/app/', 'index.index',
    '/', 'index.index'
)
```

This is where my application starts webstart.py

```
import web, urls, sys, os
def notfound():
    return web.notfound()
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = web.application(urls.urls, globals())
   app.notfound = notfound
   app.run()
```

My Apache configuration looks like this

```
<Directory "dirname">
   Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
   DirectoryIndex webstart.py
</Directory>
```

When I try to hit my server with localhost/app/, it always shows the notfound page and in the logs, I see the messsage **"WARNING: SCRIPT_NAME does not match REQUEST_URI"**

And then I tried to print those two variables in the notfound page it self and I got /app/webstart.py and /app/ respectively.

How do I let my application work when I access it with localhost/app/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt solve this problem, so used wsgi module. This is how I did it... http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/03/deploying-webpy-application-in-apache.html

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryIndex webstart.py
```

You've specified default home page for directory access in Apache configuration. So when you access some directory like URL, eg. `localhost/app/`, Apache treat this as `localhost/app/webstart.py` and then send the request to web.py. Try remove that entry from Apache configuration and restart Apache daemon.

**Update**:

When you [deploy web.py through CGI](http://webpy.org/cookbook/cgi-apache), you got an entry for the server `http://localhost/webstart.py`, given that you have `ScriptAlias`ed `/` to be your CGI script directory. And the route definitions in webstart.py comes after that url. So you should visit `http://localhost/webstart.py/app/` for your `/app/` route. You'll need some `mod_rewrite` definitions to get urls like `http://localhost/app/`.

Comment: I removed that and didnt work. It produces the following error message. "AH01265: attempt to invoke directory as script <dirname>"

Comment: Actually I am able to access it like this localhost/app/webstart.py/ but not able to access the static folder. Reading about mod_rewrite now